# Unable to get the array information in tcl loop

Tags: tcl

I am unable to print the desired 1 and 2 value of the variables in the foreach loop below. I am getting the name of the variable instead.

```
#A_voltages has 1
#B_voltages has 2
#port_1 has A
#port_2 has B
foreach v1 $port_1\_voltages {
    foreach v2 $port_2\_voltages {
        puts "-D3- v1=$v1= v2=$v2="
    }
}
```

EXPECTED RESULT:

```
-D3- v1=1 v2=2
```

CURRENT RESULT:

```
-D3- v1=A_voltages v2=B_voltages
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're trying to use nested loops, or loops at all if your variables have a single value each, but the trick is to build a variable name and pass it to `set`.

Example `tclsh` REPL session:

```
% set A_voltages 1
1
% set B_voltages 2
2
% set port_1 A
A
% set port_2 B
B
% puts "-D3 -v1=[set ${port_1}_voltages]= =[set ${port_2}_voltages]="
-D3 -v1=1= =2=
```

Note use of `${name}` to set it apart from the rest of the string.

Comment: I tried this one and it works. I need foreach because voltages can have multiple values. Thanks for your inputs

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use the "array get", as in

```
#! /usr/bin/tclsh

set A_rray(0) "X"
set A_rray(1) "Y"
set A_rray(2) "Z"
set B_rray(0) "A"
set B_rray(1) "B"
set B_rray(2) "C"
set B_rray(3) "D"

foreach L { "A" "B" } {
  puts $L
  foreach {akey aval} [array get $L\_rray ] {
    puts "$L $aval ($akey)"
  }
}
```

which gives

```
A
A X (0)
A Y (1)
A Z (2)
B
B A (0)
B B (1)
B C (2)
B D (3)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is often easiest to use `upvar` inside a procedure for this sort of thing. That lets you give variables easy-to-use names for the duration of the procedure. (Use `#0` instead of `1` to get global names, or use `namespace upvar ::` instead of `upvar`.)

```
proc iterOver {port_1 port_2} {
    upvar 1 ${port_1}_voltages p1v ${port_2}_voltages p2v

    foreach v1 $p1v {
        foreach v2 $p2v {
            puts "-D3- v1=$v1= v2=$v2="
        }
    }
}
iterOver A B
```

For one-off code, a lambda can be used (with `apply`) as an alternative.

Comment: This works with arrays as well as simple variables.